# Issue while using Hadoop Connector with Informatica 9.6.1 Hotfix 1

Tags: hadoop, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I am using Informatica 9.6.1 Hotfix 1 version. I would like to transfer a file from informatica to Hive table using Hadoop Connector. My Hadoop is secure with kerberos. I am passing below details while creating hadoop connection

```
HDFS URL
Hive Driver Name - org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
Hive URL - jdbc:hive2://hostname:portnumber/default
Hive User Name - <empty>
Hive Password - <empty>
Hadoop Distribution - Apache
```

when i execute the workflow it throws the error.

```
SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
```

This issue is coming because of Kerberos authentication and kerberos require token to authenticate. But i don't know how we can resolve it?

Could anyone please guide me to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable authentication by adding the following properties in core-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
    <value>kerberos</value> 
</property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.security.authorization</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

You need to then copy the core-site.xml to /etc/hadoop/conf directory on all machines in the cluster.